# Examples of basis

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification, natural-numbers

Excuse me , can you see this question,
For each positive integer $n$ , let $S_n=\{n,n+1,\ldots\}$ . The collection of all subsets of natural number which contain some $S_n$ is a base for a topology on $\Bbb N$ , Discribe the closure operation in this space ...

I had proved that it is a base , but i can not Describe the closure ..

I think the topology which generated by this base is as same as indiscrete one is it true ?

Comment: It's certainly not the indiscrete topology.  In the indiscrete topology on $\Bbb N$, the only open sets are $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb N$.  Here, each of the $S_n$ is an open set that is not like that.

Comment: It is not indiscrete: $\{2,3,4,\ldots\}$ is open.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No, the space is not $T_1$, see my answer.

Comment: Fun fact: there is a "five spaces theorem": consider the following five topologies on $N$: the indiscrete one, the discrete one, the cofinite one, the "up-topology" you defined with all $S_n = \{n, n+1, \ldots\}$ as a base and the "down-topology" with all sets $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$ as a base. Then any infinite topological space contains at least one of these as a subspace (up to homeomorphism).

Answer (score 0):

It's not indiscrete, that only has one open set, namely $N$. While in your topology $S_2 = \{2,3,4,5,\ldots\} \neq N$ is also open.

A typical neighbourhood of $n \in N$ is $S_n$ and so $n \in \overline{A}$ iff every neighbourhood of $N$ intersects $A$ iff $S_n$ intersects $A$ iff $A$ contains a point $m \ge n$. So $$\overline{A}=A^{\downarrow}:= \{m: \exists n \in A: m \le n\}$$

so a "downward closure". So any infinite set is dense, while the closure of $\{100\}$ is just $\{0,1,2,\ldots,100\}$ etc.

In the indiscrete topology $\overline{A}=X$ whenever $A \neq \emptyset$, which is quite different, as you can see.

Comment: Ok ,, thank you so much ,, i am sorry but i have another question if you can answer it , the collection of all open intervals (a,b) together with the one-point sets {n} for all positive and negative integer n is a base for a topology on a real line , can you please describe the interior ... Many many thanks

Comment: @Aya it’s better to post separate questions. Try to add as much of your own effort too. And learn MathJax.

Comment: Ok , i will do ,, many thanks